# What is the meaning of "big queen "?

Tags: meaning

What does "big queen" mean?
This phrase was used in the 1st episode of "the office" series.

Comment: Please supply some of the surrounding text, or a link to a video.

Comment: the guy on the phone who  sounds a little impolite and funny, started his speech in this way : hey big queen, is the...

Comment: Which "The Office"? The original British one, or the American rip-off?

Comment: @PrimeMover now now, we can’t take sides :D

Comment: From Oxford dictionary: "a homosexual man, especially one regarded as ostentatiously effeminate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salaam alaykum, Touraj. Welcome to ELL!

The colloquial use of 'big' here is similar to the use of 'great' when expressing surprise, especially in exclamations. (‘you great oaf!’). [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/great). It doesn't literally mean large, but it intensifies David Brent's friendly insult.

queen:

> *informal* A male homosexual, especially one regarded as ostentatiously effeminate.
>
> Origin
>
> Old English cwēn, of Germanic origin; related to *quean*.
>
> [ [Lexico: queen](https://www.lexico.com/definition/queen) ]

*quean* is an archaic word meaning either "An impudent or badly behaved girl or woman." or "A prostitute". Origin: Old English cwene ‘woman’, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch kween ‘barren cow’, from an Indo-European root shared by Greek gunē. [ [Lexico: quean](https://www.lexico.com/definition/quean) ]

Although, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_(slang)) says, *'queen' can either be pejorative or celebrated as a type of self-identification*, when Ricky Gervais's character uses it, greeting - presumably - a gay man, we squirm with embarrassment at his assumption that he is entitled to use the argot of the gay community. It would be similar if a white Brit addressed a black Brit, "Yo Blud!" [yourdictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/yo) [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blud) We find such such an assumption acutely embarrassing!

By the way, you may have stumbled into a never-ending argument as to whether the original UK version (14 episodes) is better than the US re-make (201 episodes) or the other way round. Or as New Zealand's [The Spinoff](https://thespinoff.co.nz/tv/13-08-2018/which-is-better-the-office-uk-or-the-office-us/) described them, "the original brutal UK version or its heartfelt US spinoff?" To Brits the US version is ingratiating. I think Americans find our attitude to work incomprehensible.

Comment: Why do you use "salaam alaykum" as a welcome?

Comment: @anouk I saw from his profile that he was living in Iran. Some of my friends are Iranian. Why do you ask?

Comment: Because as far as I know people on this forum are welcomed in English, not in the language of the country they come from. I personally prefer it that way, to me it means we are all the same. But that is just me.

Comment: hi, salam alakum is ok

Comment: but in IRAN,specially in chats,  people usually say SALAM , without ALAYKUM .It might be usual in Arabic country to use both of them. nowadays many people in Iran try not using salam and instead they say DROOD(a pesian word).